# AMQP/RabbitMQ - How to avoid race conditions

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, race-condition

I have the following architecture:
[Architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLVAA.png)

- There are a fixed number of input sources. Each input source is equivalent.
- The AMQP broker. I am using RabbitMQ in my case.
- Currently, there are 2 consumers. Again, each consumer is equivalent.

The input sources are sending commands to be processed. These commands are forwarded by the broker and picked up by one of the two consumers.

I need the following behaviour:

- If one input source sends multiple commands, all commands must be processed sequentially. That is, in the example of 2 commands, it is **not allowed** that consumer 1 is processing command 1 while consumer 2 is processing command 2 at the same time.
- However, two commands originating from two different input sources can be processed simultaneously.

Is it possible to enforce this behaviour with AMQP/RabbitMQ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cover your scenario using one consumer for each queue.
Each queue can process the message sequentially.

Another way is to use only one queue and use the `envelope.getExchange()` to understand the source, or `tag` your messages using the `AMQP.BasicProperties properties`

In this way, for example, you can consume the messages in multi-threading and assign one thread for each `tag`

Comment: I am not quite sure if this solves my problem. This prevents that a consumer has more than one message at the same time. However, and I might be wrong here, this does not prevent that another consumer receives a message originating from the same input source as the first consumer is processing at the moment?

Comment: it depends what do you mean as `broker`, do you put all the messages to the same queue ?

Comment: All messages are put in the same queue. Should I create a queue for each input source? This means that each consumer is listening to all queues?

Comment: Ok, I modified the answer,let me know if can work in this way.

Comment: Let's say I have 10 input sources. This means I have 10 queues. Let's say consumer 1 is responsible for queue 1-5 and consumer 2 for 6-10. If consumer 1 (or 2) goes down, queue 1-5 (or 6-10) won't be processed anymore. Isn't this kind of architecture an anti-pattern for the high availability properties of an AMQP?

Answer (score 0):

To guarantee sequence you may need to aggregate the messages. You can batch the commands from one source into a message before publishing to the queue, so the message into the queue can contain one or more commands that will be executed by the consumer.

Comment: I am not able to batch/collect messages before publishing. Each message should be processed as soon as possible.